# How to call a function in foreach with local variables as arguments?

Tags: prolog, constraints

I have a knapsack problem to solve in B-Prolog. I have to write something like:

```
knapsack(X, Indexes, Quantity, Weights, Values, Capacity)
```

X - array with number of ith item that is put in the bag
Indexes - [0, ..., NumOfItems-1]
Quantity - array with number of available ith items
Weights - array with weight of each item on ith position (only 1 item)
 
Value - array with value of each item (only 1 item)
Capacity - limit for bag capacity

The task must be solved using a predicate:

```
get([X|_], 0, X).
get([_|X], I, Y) :- I>0, I1 is I-1, get(X, I1, Y).
```

which returns the element on ith index, considering they can start at 0. Then Y has the value of that element.
Also, we must maximize the item values. I tried to make it work not only for fixed number of items.
Since I'm just a beginer for Prolog, I had an idea, but it doesn't wort of course.

```
knapsack(X, Indexes, Quantity, Weights, Values, Capacity) :-
    /*
        Find the last index of items, 
        Calculate NumOfItems as last index+1,
        Make an array X with NumOfItems elements,
        Define domen for each item (ith element in X) as 0..NumOfThatItem
        (meaning I can take zero or more up to the max number of that element that is avaliable)
    */
    last(Indexes, Elem),
    NumOfItems is Elem+1,
    length(X, NumOfItems),
    foreach(I in 1..NumOfItems, get(Quantity, I, K), X[I]::0..K), 

    /*
        Set up the constraint that sum of item weights must not be bigger than bag capacity
    */
    sum([X[I]*T : I in 1..NumOfItems], get(Weights, I, T)) #=< Capacity,

    /*
        Maximize the values of items in the bag, and find all possible combinations for it
    */
    labeling([maximize( sum([X[I]*V : I in 1..NumOfItems, get(Values, I, V)]))], X),

    /*
        This is the part of a task, to write out the Profit we made by taking those items,
        and the overall weight that we have put in the bag.
    */
    Profit is sum([X[I]*V : I in 1..NumOfItems, get(Values, I, V)]),
    Weight is sum([X[I]*T : I in 1..NumOfItems, get(Weights, I, T)]),
    nl,
    write('Profit: '), write(Profit), nl,

    write('Weight: '), write(Weight), nl
.
```

I am using B-Prolog Version 8.1, it can be downloaded on this [link](http://www.picat-lang.org/bprolog/download.html)(<- click) 
You can copy my code and place it in the `BProlog` folder on the location where you chose to install it.
When you open/start `bp` aplication:

```
cl('path_to_my_code.pro').
```

Exaple I have for this problem is the following:

```
knapsack(X, [0,1,2,3], [1,1,1,4], [50,10,5,1], [1000,2000,100,1], 63).
```

And that should give us:

```
Profit: 3003
Weight: 63
X = [1,1,0,3]
```

I get the following:

```
***illegal_local_variables(get([1,1,1,4], _f8, _fc))
```

I concluded that he doesn't recognize `I` as a number.
If you have any book or article or whatever related to this please share.

How should this be done? Please help...

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

At this point since you get the error you should test `get/3` predicate to see if this working properly. The problem is in the part:

```
I>0, I1 is I-1, get(X, I1, Y).
```

Since you call get with `I` as a variable, `I>0` yields instantiation error, instead you can write:

```
get([X|_], 0, X).
get([_|X], I, Y) :- get(X, I1, Y), I is I1+1, I>0.
```

Comment: I found one problematic thing, in `get` is counting from 0, and in `knapsack` I'm calling it starting from 1. So that is one thing to change.
And `I>0` is not making problems, since I already defined that for 0 is the previously defined `get([X|_], 0, X).`. Here I'm "counting backwards" that's why I'm searching for `I-1`. I don't know how to explain this logic but it works. I checked that multiple times.

Comment: Just try: `get([1,1,1,4], X, Y)` it gives instantiation error so It doesn't matter that you have a base case, still calling get/3 with variable I yields an error !!